# Difference between Python methods which is can make new variable or not

Tags: python

Some methods don't need to make a new variable, i.e. `lists.reverse()` works like this:

```
lists = [123, 456, 789]
lists.reverse()
print(lists)
```

this method make itself reversed (without new variable).
Why there is vary ways to manufacture variable in Python?
Some cases which is like `variable.method().method2().method3()` are typed continuously but `type(variable)` and `print()` are not. Why we can't typing like `variable.print()` or `variable.type()`?
Is there any philosophical reasons for Python?

Comment: Simply because Python is designed like that. And BTW method chaining is not considered best practice in Python since it reduces readability and complicates indentation.

Comment: Generally, methods which modify the value in-place, don't return a result. In some cases there may be a built-in the returns a result. For example, `reversed(seq)` which doesn't modify `seq`, but does return a result (an iterator actually, which you'd need to convert to the desired type, like `result = list(reversed(seq))`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be confused by the difference between a function and a method, and by three different purposes to them.  As much as I dislike using SO for tutorial purposes, these issues can be hard to grasp from other documentation.  You can look up function vs method easily enough -- once you know it's a (slightly) separate issue.

Your first question is a matter of system design.  Python merely facilitates what programmers want to do, and the differentiation is common to many (most?) programming languages since ASM and FORTRAN crawled out of the binary slime pools in the days when dinosaurs roamed the earth.

When you design how your application works, you need to make a *lot* of implementation decisions: individual variables vs a sequence, in-line coding vs functions, separate functions vs encased functions vs classes and methods, etc.  Part of this decision making is what each function should do.  You've raised three main types:

(1) Process this data -- take the given data and change it, rearrange it, whatever needs doing -- but I don't need the previous version, just the improved version, so just put the new stuff where the old stuff was.  This is used almost exclusively when *one* variable is getting processed; we don't generally take four separate variables and change each of them.  In that case, we'd put them all in a list and change the list (a single variable).  `reverse` falls into this class.

One important note is that for such a function, the argument in question must be *mutable* (capable of change).  Python has mutable and *immutable* types.  For instance, a list is mutable; a tuple is immutable.  If you wanted to reverse a tuple, you'd need to return a new tuple; you can't change the original.

(2) Tell me something interesting -- take the given data and extract some information.  However, I'm going to need the originals, so leave them alone.  If I need to remember this cool new insight, I'll put it in a variable of my own.  This is a function that returns a value.  `sqrt` is one such function.

(3) Interact with the outside world -- input or output data permanently.  For output, nothing in the program changes; we may present the data in an easy-to-read format, but we don't change anything internally.  `print` is such a function.

---

Much of this decision also depends on the function's designed purpose: is this a "verb" function (do something) or a noun/attribute function (look at this data and tell me what you see)?

---

Now you get the interesting job for yourself: learn the art of system design.  You need to become familiar enough with the available programming tools that you have a feeling for how they can be combined to form useful applications.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

> The `reverse()` method modifies the sequence in place for economy of space when reversing a large sequence. To remind users that it operates by side effect, it does not return the reversed sequence.